TV episode about doctor kidnapped by a crazy vampire
It's one of those horror TV series that abounded during the 80's and 90's, but this one wasn't for kids (it had to be for at least 15 years olds and older, based on this particular episode).
There was this female vampire dancing, until she trips and twists her ankle.
She starts crying in pain.
Her husband (also a vampire) gets her a doctor for a house visit.
Now, the husband vampire sees humans as nothing but food, serially kills people to feed, and is incredibly cruel (socio/psycopath levels of cruelity).
He doesn't just feeds on them out of a necessity; he actually enjoys the hunt.
The wife vampire doesn't agree to it, and feels horrible / guilty about the humans her husband feeds on. She resorts to drink blood from little animals like rats, as to avoid becoming a remorseless murderer like him. The human doctor realises this couple are actual vampires and soon it dawns on him he wasn't called to simply nurse the wife back to health; he's a meal.
The wife tries to reason with her husband to let the doctor go. I think she tried to argue gratefulness because he had cured her ankle, but the husband refused on the grounds that the human would go to his "kind" and reveal their existance, which would make them targeted and hunted.
The wife says that if the doctor were to babble around about vampires, no one would ever believe him, but it still falls on deaf ears.
The husband forces the doctor to refer to them as "master" and "mistress." As the episodes progresses, the wife starts feeling worse and worse about the doctor's predicament and the doctor starts seeing she's not like her husband. Slowly, they start falling for each other.
They end up having sex, psycho vampire arrives and LOSES IT.
I don't remember how exactly, but the doctor gets fatally injured by the psycho vampire, the psycho vampire gets killed, and the girl saves the doctor's life by turning him. Both the vampire woman and the doctor (now a vampire too) declare their love for each other.
EDIT: I think, at one point, the doctor asks her why a nice person like her is with a guy like her husband. She replies that, centuries ago, he used to be a kind, loving man, but then he started changing slowly after being turned. (I think the reason for him to snap was humans who kept trying to hunt / slay them for being vampires.)

I ended up finding it on my own. 
Wikipedia

Tales from the Darkside is an American anthology horror TV series created by George A. Romero; it debuted in 1983. Each episode was an individual short story that often ended with a plot twist. The series' episodes spanned the genres of horror, science fiction, and fantasy, and some episodes featured elements of black comedy or more lighthearted themes.

The episode in question: Strange Love

A doctor makes a late-night house call to fix a woman's leg and discovers that his patient and her husband are vampires.


Where are those quotes in your answer actually taken from? Please always list the source of anything you quote wholesale (preferrably with a link thereto).
